# Azure CLI Command for Deleting all the files in Blob storage not working for firewall enabled AZ storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I have configured a CICD pipelines for build and deploy the front end files into azure blob storage.

I configured my release pipeline to clear all files before uploading the new flies using az copy.

```
  IP=`curl -s http://ipinfo.io/json | jq -r '.ip'`
    
   echo "firewall - Agent IP: $IP"
   sleep 50 

    az storage account network-rule add -g Test_RG --account-name "Test_RG_1" --ip-address $IP
    sleep 30           
    az storage blob delete-batch --account-name  "Test_RG_1" --source '$web' 
          
    echo "Removing :$IP" 
    
    az storage account network-rule remove --account-name "Test_RG_1" --ip-address $IP
```

Above script is working fine for sometimes without any changes but its getting failed many times, throwing a error like

> ERROR: BadRequestError: (InvalidValuesForRequestParameters) Values for
> request parameters are invalid: networkAcls.ipRule[*].value. For more
> information, see - https://aka.ms/storagenetworkruleset
>
> The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account. Please
> check network rule set

[image]

Any one can you please advise me on this ?

**Reference**

[Azure Devops MS-hosted agent IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075580/azure-devops-ms-hosted-agent-ip-address)

[How to get the IP Address for Azure DevOps Hosted Agents to add to the white list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422395/how-to-get-the-ip-address-for-azure-devops-hosted-agents-to-add-to-the-white-lis)

[Azure DevOps pipeline cannot copy to Azure storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214896/azure-devops-pipeline-cannot-copy-to-azure-storage)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/storage-preview/storage?view=azure-cli-latest

[VSTS Release - Delete Azure BLOB Container / Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116200/vsts-release-delete-azure-blob-container-contents)

https://matthewleak.medium.com/deploying-a-static-website-to-azure-storage-using-azure-devops-fa0bed457d07

[Uploading File in Azure using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140075/uploading-file-in-azure-using-cli)

[Network Rules of storage account blocking container creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397786/network-rules-of-storage-account-blocking-container-creation)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, the root cause of this issue is that the IP obtained by the script is invalid.

I have encountered the same issue in the past, but it could work with the same script (IP=`curl -s http://ipinfo.io/json | jq -r '.ip'`).

When you execute the script, you could see the IP in the task log.

[image]

You can try to manually add this IP in the **Storage Account -> Networking -> firewall**.

If you could see the error like the screenshot below, this means that the IP has issue.

[image]

But based on my test, this script could work fine. The IP can also be added manually.

In addition, I run these scripts on the Microsoft-hosted agent(e.g. Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04,windows-2019) You could change to use these agents and check if it could work.

**Update:**

You could use Azure PowerShell task to set the firewall and use the Azure CLI task to execute the az cli script:

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Set Rule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0215
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -AccountName "kevin0204" -IPAddressOrRange "$IP"
     
     
     
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: ' 3.1.0'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI  Remove files'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0215
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob delete-batch --account-name kevin0204  --source kevin0204   --auth-mode login'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Remove Rule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0215
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Remove-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -AccountName "kevin0204" -IPAddressOrRange "$IP"
     
     
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: ' 3.1.0'
```

**Classic:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I have tried changing the Azure CLI scripts to Powershell task as you suggested -  Configured a scripts like                                                       
 $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "Test_RG_1"   -StorageAccountKey "kkerefcdf454fe"

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "$web" -Context $context | Remove-AzureStorageBlob            -

Comment: @Debugger. Thanks for your update. So will it work after doing this change? And If you manually added the IP(get from log) in azure storage account, will you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for quick response For adding the IP manually  I'm not getting any error.  But while performing the deletion via script I'm getting error like New-AzStorageContext is not recognized as a name of

Comment: Basically I'm trying to achieve az storage blob delete-batch --account-name  "Test_RG_1" --source '$web'  the same via Powershell task.  But I'm not sure Azure RM need to be installed in Microsoft agents or any other direct way to achieve this

Comment: @Debugger. As far as I know, the Azure PowerShell task can also run the az storage blob script(azure cli). When you execute the script, it will get error ?

Comment: On the other hand, you could directly use **Azure PowerShell task** instead of Powershell task. It will be easier.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying that same in Azuzre PowerShell task only - CLI commands in azure power shell task throwing a error like ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account - It's expecting authentication.

Comment: I trying to achieve the same via devops pipeline after firewall rules added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119087/powershell-remove-all-blobs-in-a-container - But I'm facing exact issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080159/new-azurestoragecontext-is-not-recognized-yet-the-module-is-installed/54084528

Comment: For workaround az login cli issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513537/az-login-fails-wih-azure-devops-pipelines But not sure how downgrade it via azure powershell task , Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: @Debugger. Get it. I will test it and create a sample. Then I will share it with you.

Comment: Hi @Debugger. I could reproduce this issue. ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account It seems that this az cli script still need az login. In Azure Cli task, it could work fine. So  you can put the three steps into three tasks separately and it could work.  Please refer to my update . Based on my test if you use the Powershell script to delete files ,it need to install AzureRM. This step may use more time.   The azure cli script could run directly.

Comment: Hi @Debugger. Feel free to let me know your result. If the sample could work, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks .

Comment: Thank you so much kevin, For the detail Information. I have tried based on your suggestion. Still It's failing and same scripts are working for some time. I checked the firewall settings failed IP also successfully added but it throwing a error

Comment: ERROR: 
2021-02-15T08:21:06.5865351Z The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account. Please check network rule set using 'az storage account show -n accountname --query networkRuleSet'.
2021-02-15T08:21:06.5867117Z If you want to change the default action to apply when no rule matches, please use 'az storage account update'.
2021-02-15T08:21:06.6950481Z ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1

Comment: Hi @Debugger. This issue is not same as the issue in the Orginal question. The original question is related to adding firewall, and this one is related to running az cli script after successfully adding. I notice that you have created another ticket for this new issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196473/az-storage-account-network-rule-not-working-for-microsoft-hosted-agentazure-dev. My colleague is investigating this issue now  and he wil help you in another ticket.

Comment: So may I consider this current issue has been resolved now?

Comment: Sure, Thank you So much - It helps really. Looking forward for the full solution

Comment: Hi @Debugger. Do you still have any questions about this ticket? Feel free to let me know. Thank you

Comment: Hi Kevin. Sorry primarily this request for deleting the files from Blob storage and another one is related to firewall rules. So that I'm looking and working around solutions for the same.  My storage is hosted west Europe  but this is  working on some time and not working on many time without doing any changes. Not sure whether it's related microsoft hosted agent IP address range may issues.

Comment: --auth-mode login is it's mandatory to give this option in our script?

Comment: `--auth-mode ` This is optional. Because the azure cli task already contains the login credentials, it can be used directly.  The alternative is to use these： `--sas-token` , `--account-key` .

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, this issue could be related with Hosted Agent IP. Every time you run microsoft-hosted agent his ip will change. This should be related to your organization region.

Comment: Yeah.. - My Organization region is West Europe. But we are getting the Microsoft Hosted agent IP dynamically and adding the same firewall. So according to me it should not block, Not sure what's wrong in the process..

Comment: Do you mean the issue in this ticket? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196473/az-storage-account-network-rule-not-working-for-microsoft-hosted-agentazure-dev

Comment: Yes, It's related to Firewall configuration

Comment: For a workaround, you could try to use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Comment: Hi @Debugger. Do you have any questions about current ticket? If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it. For the new issue, you could monitor this issue in our Feedback site:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1337796/azure-cli-scripts-to-delete-blob-files-not-working.html

Comment: Hi @Kevin.  Thank  you so much for your assistance.  In developer community also I already referred this post. Not sure this a new issue. New issue similar related to firewall I raised here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196473/az-storage-account-network-rule-not-working-for-microsoft-hosted-agentazure-dev. Sorry Still that too I'm not good with the suggestions for that also. I'm looking for some permanent solution for this problem. I hope you understand my concern.

Comment: Self Hosted is not cost effective right while comparing to Microsoft hosted agent ? Any thoughts on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser